# Is there a way to copy saved tasks files into Outlook from the command line?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

There are many tasks I complete each month. I've created Outlook Task, then saved them externally (.msg) to a folder outside Outlook. Each month I copy these task into Outlook via drag and drop from the folder to the task pane. This works fine, but would like to automate it.

I would like to use a batch file to copy the task files into Outlook Tasks (I'm not looking to make templates for creating tasks in Outlook). I searched multiple sources, but have not found any information for commands to do this.

For what it's worth, I am using Windows 7, with Outlook 2010 in Exchange mode.

Is there a way to copy task files into Outlook from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy them into:

> C:\Users[YOUR NAME]\AppData\Local\AppointmentStyler\Templates\

Comment: That will place them in the Task Pane? That path doesn't exist. Can you clarify?

Comment: This is the location for active tasks - what Windows Version are you running?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 on a network with Exchange. The path you mention above does not exists. There is no "AppoinmentStyler" folder.